# ∀a,b,c∈ Z, if a|b and a|c then a^2|(5b^2 + 7c^3)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My question is Prove the statement. ∀a,b,c∈ Z, if a|b and a|c then a^2|(5b^2 + 7c^3) I'm really stuck and have no idea where to start. any help would be great!

Comment: Write $b=ak$ and $c=al$ where $k$ and $l$ are integers. Express $5b^2+7c^3$ in terms of $a$, $k$, and $l$. You should be able to factor out $a^2$.

Comment: is it as simple as a^2(5k + 7la)??

Comment: Yes, and $5k+7la$ is an integer, so you have your divisibility.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that if $a|b$ and $a|c$, then $a|b+c$.

Now try to prove that $a^2|b^2$ and $a^2|c^3$ and use the above theorem to finally show

$$a^2|5b^2+7c^3$$